# Deploying a Play Application to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I have a play application that I created using the activator ui, I am now trying to deploy and run this to an Amazon EC2 instance. I am having a lot of problems doing this and also have a few questions.

Overview of my app: This is an application that is designed to be a ReSTful web application, that responds to get requests from our client. There will also be user interface portion and data display portion that I will be creating.

Question 1: On my EC2 instance, I am currently running a mysql database that i am using to store the data for my application. Can i run my application on the same server as the database or will this cause problems?

Question 2: What is the simplest way to deploy and run my application on the server? I have tried using a service called boxfuse but i am not having much luck with it so I was wondering if there is a way to turn the project into .zip files or .war files or something and put them on the server using WinSCP, unzip it, and then run it on the server. I have found some guides online but have had trouble getting them to work, I have managed to create a zip but cant get it to run. Can anyone post or link a step by step guide to simply zipping/packaging my project, putting it on the server, and then running it? Thank you and i greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Using an EC2 instance would defeat the purpose of a "serverless" architecture. I'd recommend leveraging this architecture by following static page web design. Host your html/js from an S3 bucket and render data via api gateway+lambda+(kinesis+db).. etc

Comment: Would you mind sharing which problems you had with Boxfuse?

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: On my EC2 instance, I am currently running a mysql
>   database that i am using to store the data for my application. Can i
>   run my application on the same server as the database or will this
>   cause problems?

You can run MySql on the same machine as long as there are enough resources to run both - CPU/Memory etc. So you need to consider what size instance you deploy to.

> Question 2: What is the simplest way to deploy and run my application
>   on the server? ...

I have deployed a few Play apps on AWS and from trying different approaches, by far the best way I have found yet is to use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html).

There are many tutorials on AWS for how to deploy using Beanstalk. There is also a [Template on Lightbend](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-elastic-beanstalk) that will give you some insight.

Read about the [dist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Using-the-dist-task) task that the SBT native packager plugin provides for creating zip or tarball.

Comment: I have tried using the tempate of elastic beanstalk here 

https://github.com/kipsigman/play-elastic-beanstalk

However , when i come to the step of :

sbt elastic-beanstalk:dist

i get this error :

[error] (*:dockerCommands) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

however when i run 

dist

everything goes well , however when i upload the output zip found in the directory of target/universal to aws i get error in aws console :

No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.